# How do I know when a session is first created in Vaadin 7.x?

Tags: java, session, vaadin7

I'd like to know the first time a session is created in Vaadin so I can write various data that'll be kept from request to request. Some kind of application-level listener for when a session is created/destroyed. Is this possible?

-- Shane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, Create a class that implements **javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener** and annotate it with **@WebListener** which gives you access to method sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed.

Sample Code -

```
@WebListener
public class UserSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Session Created");

    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Session Destroyed");

    }

}
```

That is all you have to do.

Comment: As of the Servlet 3.0 spec, you can use annotations for this rather than using a web.xml file. Described [here](http://explodingjava.blogspot.com/2010/05/servlet-30-annotations.html).

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me... I will modify the answer based on doc you shared